# Use mod_rewrite to remove year and month from wordpress post's url, while keeping year and month permalink structure

Tags: wordpress, url, mod-rewrite

I've been around the world and back with this mod_rewrite syntax and I'm having a hard time constructing some working rewrite rules.

#### Scenario:

Working in Wordpress, I want to remove "year/month" from the url structure while keeping the year/month custom permalink activated. Reason being I'm using a plugin that generates a category specific archive, but the plugin is dependent on the permalink structure being:

```
/%cateogry%/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%
```

#### Goal:

I want to change this path: `category/2010/12/post-name`

to this path: `category/post-name`

#### Condition:

**If** the year/month is present in the url and it is followed by a forward slash (`/`) with characters after the slash (eg. `category/2010/12/post-name`) 
{

```
Remove the year/month from the url;

// intended output: category/post-name

// in this case I am directly clicking on a link.
```

} else {

```
//leave it alone; 
//intended output: category/2010/12/


/*=======
In this case I am already in the archive section and will want the 
plugin to display the archive according to the year & category

=======*/
```

}

I have this rule written in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^category/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/$         news/$1 [L, NC]
```

Can anyone help please (if you can, explain some of the things you are doing so I can familiarize myself more with it)?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little confusing, but let me see if I understand.

You want to change:

```
http://somehost.com/category/2011/11/some-post
```

to:

```
<webroot>/category/some-post
```

If that's the case, you're almost there.  In the rewrite you have a backreference ($1), but that backreference isn't defined anywhere in the search pattern.  In order to define a backreference, you surround the portion with parenthesis.  Updating your rule would look like this (also taking into account a variable category):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ $1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sadly, after uploading with the new rule, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

 Message: The request was not completed. The server met an unexpected condition.
my_server_IP/my_sitename / (port 80)

Comment: codes for my htaccess file below
---------------------------

# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / my_sitename /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / my_sitename /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L, NC]

Comment: Oops.  I just copied your rule and didn't notice the space between the flags--that shouldn't be there, and I have updated the rule.  Also, I removed the leading slash as that will redirect it to a directory off of the webroot instead of relative to the local directory.

Comment: Did you try my updates noted above?  If that still doesn't work, please post the error from your apache error_log.

Comment: Just got it thanks. I tried the new line. There are no more errors. However, it isn't working. I noticed sometime ago, I tried to change the site file extensions from .php to .asp using regex in the htaccess file and it did it successfully. But only in the wordpress admin panel and not for the site. Do you think the syntax you've written might be affecting the admin panel and not the site? The htaccess file is located in the 'public_html' folder where the core wordpress files are.

Answer (score -1):

goto Admin - Settings - Permalinks

Select custom structure and use

```
/%postname%/
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that. Because a plugin that I am using to generate category-specific archives are dependant on the permalink structure being: /%cateogry%/%year% /%monthnum% /%postname% if I change it to any other structure the plugin is no longer working. Ultimately,  when I click on the link "december 2010" I need the category-name/year/month in the url so the plugin can display post for the specific category for that year and month. But if I don't click on the archive link, and I click directly on a post anywhere else on the site, I wanted to url to look like: category-name/post-name

Comment: I recommend going to wordpress.stackexchange.com, there are some more focussed folks there

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will definitely do that.